# my lua code doesn't work and it gives me the error "attempt to compare function with number stack traceback:"

Tags: lua, user-input

i am trying to make a program that asks you your age and then give you output as shown below

```
local age=io.read
if age<=12 then
    print("you are young")
    if (age>12) and (age<=21)  then
    print("you are a teenager")
        if (age > 21) and (age <= 50) then
          print("you are an adult")
            if age > 50 then
            print ("your are old")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In addition to Roberts fix you may also want to recheck your conditions. For example, you check if the person is an adult if the person is a teenager. Which is never true.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

```
Lua 5.4.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> io.read
function: 0000000065b9f460
> io.read()
2332 <--------- user type the number 2332
2332
>
```

The expression `io.read` refer to the function named [`io.read`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.read). If one need to call this function, the Lua language requires the use of parenthesis:

```
ageString = io.read()
                   ^^ Missing in the provided code
```

[`io.read`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.read) will return a `string` which need to be converted into a number before being able to compare it with another number. For this, one could use the built-in function [tonumber](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-tonumber).

```
local ageString=io.read()
local age = tonumber(ageString)
if age<=12 then
    print("you are young")
    if (age>12) and (age<=21)  then
    print("you are a teenager")
        if (age > 21) and (age <= 50) then
          print("you are an adult")
            if age > 50 then
            print ("your are old")
            end
        end
    end
end
```